# Create Unit tests for Elasticsearch query in .net

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a microservice used to search in Elasticsearch documents (Using Elasticsearch.Net and NEST). I want to add some unit tests to test my Query on the SearchAsync method. Is there a way to mock the IElasticSearch client in order to get some documents and apply the Query on this documents? I managed to mock the SearchAsync method to return an ISearchResponse but this does not apply the Query on documents.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't test a query without ElasticSearch. When replacing that with a Mock you would test the Mock not Elasticsearch. That does not help. You might still want to test the surrounding code creating/reacting to a query but for that what you have should be sufficient.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433412/290460 how I would test Elasticsearch queries these days